# Apache Beam Saving to BigQuery using Scio and explicitly specifying TriggeringFrequency

Tags: scala, google-bigquery, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I'm using `Spotify Scio` to create a scala Dataflow pipeline which is triggered by a `Pub/Sub` message. It reads from our private `DB` and then inserts information into `BigQuery`.

The problem is:

- I need to delete the previous data
- For this, I need to use write disposition `WRITE_TRUNCATE`
- But, the job is automatically registered as streaming and thus I get the following error: `WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE is not supported for an unbounded PCollection`
- So I need to manually change the pipeline to be a `Batch` pipeline, specifying a triggering frequency.

So until now I had the following pipeline:

```
sc
  .customInput("Job Trigger", inputIO)
  .map(handleUserInformationRetrieval(dbOperationTimeout, projectName))
  .flatten
  .withGlobalWindow(options = windowOptions(windowingOutputTriggerDuration))
  .groupBy(_.ssoId)
  .map { case (ssoId, userDataCollection) => Schemas.toTableRow(ssoId, userDataCollection) }
  .filter(_.isSuccess)
  .map(_.get)
  .saveAsBigQuery(tableName, getSchema, WRITE_TRUNCATE, CREATE_NEVER)
```

I can't seem to find a way to specify a Trigger Frequency when I use the `scio` api (`saveAsBigQuery`).

It's only present in the native `beam` api:

```
BigQueryIO
  .write()
  .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardDays(1)) // This is what I'm after
  .to(bqTableName)
  .withSchema(getSchema)
  .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_NEVER)
  .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_TRUNCATE)
```

If I use the `BigQueryIO` I'll have to use `sc.pipeline.apply` instead of my current pipeline.

Is there a way to somehow integrate the `BigQueryIO` to my current pipeline or somehow specify `withTriggeringFrequency` on the current pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scio currently doesn't support specifying the method to be used for loading data to Big Query. Since this is not possible, automatically `STREAMING_INSERTS` is used for unbounded collections, which obviously can't support truncation. Therefore, you need to fallback to Beam's `BigQueryIO` specifying a triggering frequency (`withTriggeringFrequency(...)`) and method (`withMethod(Method.FILE_LOADS)`).

To integrate it in your Scio pipeline, you can simply use `saveAsCustomOutput`. 
An example can also be found here: https://spotify.github.io/scio/io/Type-Safe-BigQuery#using-type-safe-bigquery-directly-with-beams-io-library

Comment: but i'm not using file loads as a trigger

Comment: Triggering frequency defines when loading data to Big Query is triggered. This can only work when using `FILE_LOADS`. Please have a look at the docs: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withTriggeringFrequency-org.joda.time.Duration-

So if you want to use `WRITE_TRUNCATE` this is the only chance to make it work.